# Bug when Import Eclipse keybinding

Tags: eclipse

I was customizing my keybinding in Eclipse. Then I did an export key preference to a .epf file. After that, I imported it to Eclipse.

Then everytime I use the customized keybinding, instead of performing the expected action, Eclipse just shows a small popup at the bottom right corner and I need to use arrow key to select the action then press enter.

This has been very annoying. Does anyone know how to fix this bug yet?

For example, below is my customized <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to delete a line.

[image: Custom Eclipse]

After being customized and exported to .epf, then I imported it into Eclipse again. When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>, a small popup will be shown at the bottom right corner, instead of deleting a line.

[image: Showing issue]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried doing this and it worked fine for me.

The "Go to Line" in your screen dump indicates that the default key mapping is still there somehow. Maybe your Eclipse workspace is corrupt. Try it on a fresh workspace.

The key configuration is stored in

```
[workspace]\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.runtime\.settings\org.eclipse.ui.workbench.prefs
```

Check if everything looks OK in there.

Comment: Which OS are you using? It worked fine if I'm running Eclipse in Windows. This problem only happens when I run Eclipse in Ubuntu. 
I tried to switch to a new fresh workspace (in Ubuntu), but the annoying popup still appear...

Comment: I have tried it on Windows and Red Hat. The key configuration is stored in .metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.runtime\.settings\
org.eclipse.ui.workbench.prefs in your workspace. Check if everything looks OK in there.

Comment: Hi ellak, thank you for replying. I've looked at the configuration files that you mentioned. It seem to have some conflicts there. I've managed to get it resolved. I'm more familiar with Visual Studio key binding, so I'm trying to configure Eclipse keybinding to match VS.
P.S. I wanna post my before (problem epf file) and after (fixed epf file) here, but SO limit the length of my comment @@

Comment: Perhaps you can post it as a new answer to this question